# SQL insert and update in the same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey I have a query that will insert into the table a new data and I want that in the same time update an outher table with the id of the new data that I have entered. ex:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) VALUES ('Mark')");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `test` WHERE `name` = 'Mark'");
$id = mysql_result($query,0);
mysql_quey("UPDATE `test2` SET `test_id` = $id WHERE `name` = 'Mark'");
```

How do I do it at same time? because doing it this way I only insert the new data and I dont update the other.

Cumps.

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the backticks in your values and replace with quotes.

Comment: Try to look for the **MERGE** Statement.

Comment: `insert` queries can only target a single table. you would need to run multiple separate queries, or use a trigger.

Comment: Looks like my comment's NULL & VOID now; from the looks of someone's edit. Was it valid? Was it the fault? Who knows. We're not allowed to modify code, but fix indents and text typos.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it will work if I do?

Comment: You can give it a try. Someone edited your code btw.

Comment: Did you consider the use of a trigger?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd You shouldn't edit "code". Sometimes, this can be part of the problem to someone's code. We can edit tags, text typos and indents, but not "fix" code. I voted for your edit as being invalid, but it seems others thought differently.

Comment: @user3745394 If ever you post another question and someone edits your code and feel that it's invalid, you can reject it. If other editors approve it yet you do not approve, you can always do a rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) VALUES ('Mark')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_quey("UPDATE `test2` SET `test_id` = $id WHERE `name` = 'Mark'");
```

I've changed the backticks to single quotes in your first insert for the values, backticks should never be used for field values.

Also I've changed it to use only two queries, the mysql_insert_id() will get the last inserted id without you needing to query it.

Ref : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Voted UP, since you fixed the backticks issue, where an invalid edit was done and may have contributed to OP's issue. Plus, giving the OP the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need the select to get the id, there is `mysql_insert_id()` for that.

Then you have to use a transaction to make both queries feel like executed at the same time:

```
mysql_query('BEGIN');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) VALUES ('Mark')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("UPDATE `test2` SET `test_id` = $id WHERE `name` = 'Mark'");
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

A transaction makes sure both statements are executed, and no other script can come between them in any way.

Comment: +1, I don't understand why someone voteminus you, because your reply is the only good solution! The transactions are essential when multiples mutually dependent queries must be executed…